# how to configure the advanced forum module in drupal

Tags: drupal

How does one restrict the advanced forum module in drupal to show only on certain forum pages? As in how to configure it for forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [Adding functionality to your forum with contribs](http://drupal.org/node/227121)